# Sending POST by Measurement Protocol to tracking goals

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Our service sending a POST query to https://www.google-analytics.com/collect by CURL in PHP.
With params: v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-1&cid=516036575.1201189458&t=event&ec=end&ea=pay&el=goal_pay&ip=43.6&z=150667407947

But in Google Analytic we didn't receive the data.

We tried to send a query by Hit Builder but didn't got data too.

Here is a goal settings in GA: http://joxi.ru/Dr89Bn0t4qZoxm
Here is a answer from the Debug: http://joxi.ru/BA0bE43hJxlPKm

Comment: Have you check it on the event section of your google analytics account? and where you get  `z` parameter?

Comment: Yes, there is some data, not all. Parametr z is from the doc https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference?hl=ru#-

Answer (score 3):

I pasted that code on the hit builder and it said that you are missing 'tid' parameter. Also for the future remember you can send hits to:

https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect

And the response will be a validation of your hit.